# How to Create Device with D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, hlsl, directx9

I'm trying to create a DirectX9 device to copy video frame data from one memory buffer to another while processing it through a HLSL shader. I will need half-float or float precision for each channel. For now, D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F will do.

I can create the device when passing D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8 in the presentation parameters, but it will fail when passing D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F. I don't want to display this on the screen nor convert it between formats. Both the source and destination texture buffers have the same format.

How can I create a device that will allow me to display the output into another texture of type D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use `CheckDeviceFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174312(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine if a given `D3DFORMAT` is suitable for the device's backbuffer; it's unlikely that particular format will be.

Instead, try creating the device with any old acceptable backbuffer format (`D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8` for example); it doesn't matter since you won't be rendering to it.

Then create a new texture with the desired destination format (`D3DFMT_A32B32G32R32F`), [set it as a render target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174455(v=vs.85).aspx), and render to *that*.